# Получение адекватного отклика от модема (AT)

Tags: java, at

Отправляю через OutputStram AT команды на dial-up модем Acorp. Команды проходит, модем "поднимает трубку". Пытаюсь прочитать отклик через InputStream и выдаёт [B@127734f Что это такое? Вроде "обещали", что если команда проходит - модем должен выдавать "OK".
Есть у кого-нить какие-нить соображения по этому поводу?
Спасибо.

```
package server;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Enumeration;

import gnu.io.*;

public class Test {
    CommPortIdentifier portIdentifer;
    CommPort commPort;
    SerialPort serialPort;

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public Test() {
        try {
            portIdentifer = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier("/dev/ttyS0");
        }
        catch (NoSuchPortException nspe) {
            System.out.println("нет таких портов");
        }
        if (portIdentifer.isCurrentlyOwned()) {
            System.out.println("Error: Port is currently in use");
        }
        else {
            try {
                commPort = portIdentifer.open(this.getClass().getName(),2000);
            }
            catch (PortInUseException piue) {
                System.out.println("порт используется");
            }
            if (commPort instanceof SerialPort) {
                serialPort = (SerialPort) commPort;
                try {
                    serialPort.setSerialPortParams(57600, SerialPort.DATABITS_8, SerialPort.STOPBITS_1, SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
                }
                catch (UnsupportedCommOperationException ucoe) {
                    System.out.println("не проходит операция");
                }
                try {
                    InputStream is = serialPort.getInputStream();
                    OutputStream os = serialPort.getOutputStream();
                    String massageOn = "AT V1 H1 \r";
                    String massageOff = "AT H0 \r";
                    os.write(massageOn.getBytes());
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[10000];
                    is.read(buffer);
                    System.out.println(buffer.toString());

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {

                    }
                    os.write(massageOff.getBytes());

                }
                catch (IOException ioe) {
                    System.out.println("инпут-аутпут");
                }

                //(new Thread(new SerialReader(is))).start();
                //(new Thread(new SerialWriter(os))).start();
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Error: Only serial ports are handled by this example.");
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                serialPort.close();
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                System.out.println("interrupted");
            }

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[B@127734f   - это тип [B - массив байтов @127734f - адрес массива. Это всё потому, что вы неправильно пытаетесь отобразить массив байтов в строку. Метод [toString](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) для массива (точнее, для базового java.lang.Object) реализован таким образом, что вы всегда будете видеть нечто подобное. Чтобы что-то увидеть, надо вместо

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[10000];
is.read(buffer);
System.out.println(buffer.toString());
```

Писать иначе.. ну, хотя бы так (хотя, это не совсем верно):

```
int rc;
byte[] buffer = new byte[512];
rc = is.read(buffer);
if (rc != -1)
    System.out.println(new String(buffer, 0, rc, "ISO-8859-1"));
```

Кроме того, ваш код выглядит.. как-то странно.. выглядит некрасиво.. советую почитать про обработку ошибок в Java чтобы сделать код изящнее.

**UPD** Если уверены, что точно должно быть OK, то можно написать что-то в этом роде

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "ISO-8859-1"));
try {
    os.write(command.getBytes());
    if (!"OK".equals(br.readLine()))
        throw new IllegalStateException("Bad modem response");
// .... и так далее в таком духе
} finally {
    br.close();
}
```

Comment: При использовании ISO-8859-1 выдавал 0.
Корректный ответ удалось получить при использовании кодировки US-ASCII

Answer (score 1):

Модем не обязательно должен отвечать OK в случае успешного выполнения команды. Вид ответа [определяется](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayes_command_set) предыдущими командами или настройками по умолчанию. К примеру,

- V0 - цифровые коды результата,
- Q1 - отсутствующие коды результата.

Ну, и возможно, что в Java-коде что-то не то.

Comment: А после ATDP/ATDT модем вообще открывает сессию с удаленным хостом и там почти наверняка будут гнаться бинарные данные

Comment: Да-да, в Java-коде СОВСЕМ не то